Is it possible to use a cog RGB GeoTiff with ol-cesium in 3D
I am trying to load a cloud-optimized RGB geotiff, using ol-cesium:
new TileLayer({
    source: new GeoTIFF({
        sources: [
            {
                url: "my_rgb_cog.tiff",
            }
        ],
        convertToRGB: function(rasterData) { return [rasterData[1], rasterData[2], rasterData[0]]; }    // Manually swap channels, as otherwise colors look wrong
    })
});

I used to get error "Error: Rendering array data is not yet supported", but got it fixed replacing my original import:
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';

with:
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/WebGLTile';

This works using ol-cesium in 2D/OpenLayers mode only.
However, once I switch to 3D, the layer is not shown, and there is no error regardless of whether I use Tile or WebGLTile.
Is there a way to get cloud-optimized RGB geotiffs working in 3D/Cesium mode?

It seems this is currently a limitation in ol-cesium: https://github.com/openlayers/ol-cesium/issues/1063
